# Adding GLM to Xcode 5.1 Project

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, glm-math

I added GLM directory by *Add Files to "project_name"*, then added: `#include "glm.hpp"` in main.cpp and during a compilition I had a following error.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Grab the glm file and put it into your project at the same hierarchy and then go header searcher paths and add the source root like im indicating in the photo. [image]